# Viewing/Loading downloaded Logs in Developer Console

Tags: apex, developer-console, debugging, debug-logs

Developer Console is a really powerful tool when it comes to debugging logs (specially with different perspectives). Developer Console provides an option to download logs, but is there a way to view/load a downloaded log so as to get prespectives as shown below.

[image]

If not is there any support for the same in VS Code (Salesforce Extension Pack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't download the different perspectives; they are a feature of the client-side software that is the Developer Console. There's nothing quite like it anywhere else that I know of.

That said, the [Apex Interactive Debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-apex-debugger) for VS Code allows you to run through your code as if it were locally executing code, where you can examine the stack, variables, set breakpoints, etc. It's probably the best officially supported Salesforce development feature.

It's possible that some other IDEs (such as IntelliJ) offer similar features, but I can't claim to be familiar with any of them with the level of experience I have with VS Code--it's my go-to choice for development in Salesforce, and has been for a number of months now (obviously, this is my opinion, you're invited to do your own research).

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. I've used Apex Interactive Debugger, it's a great tool. Btw I don't want to download perspectives. I have a previously downloaded log file and I want to view it in Developer Console. Let me know if the question needs editing.

Comment: @PranavParakh Oh. Unfortunately, you can only load logs that are still available in the org. You can't just upload any log you'd like. This is a limitation of the Developer Console.